# Police-panic mode for Apple Watch?

Tags: security, password, apple-watch

On iPhone you can immediately lock all sensitive information by pressing the side button five times.

On Mac you can hold down the power button.

What is the equivalent for Apple Watch?

Also, since your Apple Watch can unlock your phone and/or Mac, what is the full panic sequence needed to secure all Apple digital devices from a "break down your door, hands up" threat actor?

Comment: This certainly makes one wonder what you are up to that you need to hide from the police! 

Comment: "Police" is a fun way to say it. But more generally, I've been kidnapped before and I want to be prepared for any duress situation that might come up again in life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your iPhone in the Apple Watch app, scroll down to Passcode.  Create a Passcode then enable “Turn Passcode On”.  Scroll down and enable Wrist Detection. With that enabled, anytime your Apple Watch is not on your wrist, passcode needs to be entered to access any of the watch functions.

However, if they are hell-bent on accessing your watch information, while you are wearing the watch… nothing is stopping them from cutting your arm off and using your watch while it’s still on your wrist LOL

Comment: Simply put… with the passcode set up correctly, simply take your watch off when the cops come busting down your door.

Comment: Couldn't the watch be on any wrist or it it somehow registered to ones body for this feature?

Comment: It does not make a difference. Once you take it off your wrist and put it back on any wrist, the passcode needs to be entered again

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It would be nice if the duress sequence was just as easy as logging in -- taking off your watch locks your phone and computers.